# How to install django on ubuntu?

Tags: django, pip

Im trying to install Django.

When I use `sudo apt-get install pip`, there is an error `pip not found`.

I used `sudo easy_install pip`, there is an error `command easy_install` not found.

I used `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv`, even that is not working.

Comment: You are trying to install the wrong package `pip`, its `python-pip`.

Answer (score 0):

You can install pip using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

django using

```
sudo apt-get install python-django
```

---

#### Tip to know the correct package name to install:

If you know what the package you are trying to install does, you can search its exact name using `apt-cache search` as follows:

```
apt-cache search pip | grep install
```

I grep it with `install` since I know pip is used to install python libraries, so "install" might be in the summary for `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best workflow would be:

- Install easy_install:

`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

- Install latest version of pip with easy_install:

`sudo easy_install pip`

- Once pip installed install django:

`sudo pip install django`

Having said this, I would recommend you [install django via venv](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/) since it's not a good practice install it system wide.